# Alternative source for most read-only database records

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization

There is a MySQL database table include Persons records and they filled once and then they will not changes later, but will be used several times in various type for preview and most important issue is that they are more than 1000 records and will showing as paging in various sort of Name, LName, Address, Code etc. Also they will use in search form and the search form has filter option.

Due to the above description and the unnecessary features which is in database (MySQL) (i.e. connection, insert, edit) advise me alternative source which I can create it from database after each changing data and then using it for preview and search.
I was thinking about text file as json format but it's not good idea because it will use RAM and cpu to be prepared.
if it's important so language is PHP.

So:

I need an alternative to create a source file from one big MySQL database table records which will use as read-only but include sort, search, filter option and without inserting, modifying, connection feature.

Comment: Well... What your asking doesn't make much sense but I guess you know what you're doing. Maybe you could try putting everything in a CSV file?

Comment: I don't see a reason to not use database for the above situation, but if you really don't want then text files is your alternative. if you are worried about RAM and CPU usage then you can do paging/filtering.

Comment: "It will use ram and cpu to be prepared" and sourcing it from the db is free?? Saying that if you don't call those 'unnecessary' features' they don't really matter do they?

Comment: For searching and retrieving data in thousands of records, a database if by far the best choice.

Comment: Have you considered placing a cache in front of the DB calls? An in-memory cache such a memcached is ideal for optimizing data retrieval times for slowly changing data like this.

Comment: for those are talking about database please advice special database, does SQLite is better than MySQL for most-read-only records?

Comment: @Hamid Hamid what you are talking about is a cache.  Caches are ideal for slowly changing data where read loads are expected to greatly exceed write loads.  Though you data access pattern will really determine how cacheable your data is.  If you are making a bunch of varied filters, sorts, etc. then perhaps teh results are not very cacheable.  If you have a consistent pattern to how you query this data, then it would be highly cacheable, and in fact MySQL's built in query cache would provide significant performance improvement by having query results cached in memory.

Comment: @MikeBrant Query cache is not useful when I have various filter/where SELECT query because Query cache will store the RESULT of the query and it is useful for non-where SELECT query I think, isn't it?

Comment: @Hamid If you are using only a small number of filter/ordering combinations on a slow changing data table, the query cache will provide benefit.  If your queries are filtering for a single row, then perhaps query cache would not be effective, but this is a case where an in-memory caching layer would be very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SQLite is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to provide editing on each record, but just be able to display them and sort them, you could still use the database to store, but fetch all (or parts) of the dataset and display them on a page using Datatables (https://datatables.net/).

That plugin will enable you to sort, search and everything on the browser.